# Borders' size in WebView are rendered differently

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a mobile webpage which I'm viewing with WebView but for some reason it renders the borders differently - 1px OR 2px thick. Has anyone experienced that?

So the sample picture below shows how a div with 1px top and 1px bottom border is rendered with 1px top and 2px bottom. This problem occurs in other places too, which makes the design look cheap...

Any suggestions?

[image]

**SOME CODE**

ACTIVITY

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deleteDatabase("webview.db");
        deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         mywebview.loadUrl("http://example.mobi/");
         WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HTML**

```
...
 <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0;">
<div id="mobilesStatusSubmit">
   post status
</div>
....
```

**CSS**

```
div#mobilesStatusSubmit{
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
padding-top:10px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #2684b0;
text-align: center;
background: white;
display: block;
border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;

}
```

**PHONE**

Galaxy S2

Comment: attached what screen you are getting and what your requirement

Comment: The picture is from a webpage that I'm viewing through WebView. It is designed with html/css and on a regular browser both borders look fine 1px thick, but looking at it in WebView it shows some of the borders thicker. I've checked my html meta tag and it is supposed to be correct `target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0;`

Comment: in browser and in mobile webview the page might be same but little difference will be attached with your complete code..i will try to help you or website itself

Comment: I've added code to the question so it makes it more clear.

Comment: I'm looking at the app on a Galaxy S2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem and it is well explained in the following tutorial.

Apparently the screen density affects the border and because my Galaxy S2 is ~1.5pixel density 1px becomes 2 in some of the borders (probably ~half of the time)

https://web.archive.org/web/20120703185504/http://bradbirdsall.com/mobile-web-in-high-resolution

Hope this helps to others.

Comment: This solution makes the borders none in css and creates the borders using box-shadow property. Anyway this works and gave the immediate solution. +1

Comment: "404 We couldn’t find this page." Could you explain or add some code example @Ando? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did u try this...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deleteDatabase("webview.db");
        deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
       mywebview .setKeepScreenOn(true);
            mywebview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mywebview .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
             mywebview .getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
             mywebview .setInitialScale(100);
            mywebview .getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
             mywebview .setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
              mywebview .setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            mywebview.loadUrl("http://example.mobi/");
           WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
           webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
```

Comment: Janmejoy, where do I put this code? I've changed it a bit because it gives me errors.. `WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);` .To be honest I don't understand the language very much. I just want to make a quick version of my website. Can you explain with regards to the code where do I have to put it. So far i tried to put it before and after `mywebview.loadUrl` but nothing happened. Thanks for helping me out on this.

Comment: thanks i had to change  `mywebview .setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());` to `mywebview .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` in order to make it work but the page looks the same. :( The top border is still thicker.